# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Cleaner

Tags: java, java-9, undertow

When using Undertow 1.4.20 (as embedded Servlet engine), i get this exception when running our app under Java 9.=: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Cleaner`

Cause is this line in `io.undertow.server.DirectByteBufferDeallocator`:

```
tmpCleanerClean = Class.forName("sun.misc.Cleaner").getMethod("clean");
```

This class does indeed not exists anymore in Java 9. But a replacement is available: `java.lang.ref.Cleaner`

Can i ignore this exception for now? Is there a timeline for fixing this (i.e. making undertow Java 9 compatible)?

Comment: This looks like something to submit to the undertow issue tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a bug, resolved in 2.0.0.Alpha2 and 1.4.21.Final.

See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-1187